# List of Vote type IDs

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

This is mainly for SEDE use.

I know the basic `VoteTypeId`s, like 1 for accept, 2 for upvote, and 3 for downvote. There are also some other less well-known ones like 11 for undelete.

Is there a complete list somewhere I can refer to?

Comment: It contains the answer to your question, plus extra information.

Comment: There's an [icon on these kinds of tables](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3vmz9.png) in the schema that you can click to get a [list of values with their labels](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OLRvw.png), for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the `SELECT id, name FROM VoteTypes` on the Data Explorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/102390/vote-types

The results:

```
Id | Name
-- | ----------------------
1  | AcceptedByOriginator
2  | UpMod
3  | DownMod
4  | Offensive
5  | Favorite
6  | Close
7  | Reopen
8  | BountyStart
9  | BountyClose
10 | Deletion
11 | Undeletion
12 | Spam
15 | ModeratorReview
16 | ApproveEditSuggestion
```

Comment: I wonder what happened to 13 and 14.